# select manipulation in PHP

Tags: php, forms, wordpress

```
$checkbox_field = "<select name='subscribe-reloaded' id='subscribe-reloaded'>
                <option value='none'>".__("Don't subscribe",'subscribe-reloaded')."</option>
                <option value='yes'".((get_option('subscribe_reloaded_checked_by_default', 'no') == 'yes')?" selected='selected'":'').">".__('All','subscribe-reloaded')."</option>
                <option value='replies'>".__('Replies to my comments','subscribe-reloaded')."</option>
                <!-- option value='digest'>".__('Daily digest','subscribe-reloaded')."</option -->
            </select>";
```

This is a plugin I'm using which makes "ALL" by default, I can't quite figure how to make "replies to my comments only" the default.

Comment: that part selected='selected' is selected by the getOption value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$checkbox_field = "<select name='subscribe-reloaded' id='subscribe-reloaded'>
                <option value='none'>".__("Don't subscribe",'subscribe-reloaded')."</option>
                <option value='yes'>".__('All','subscribe-reloaded')."</option>
                <option value='replies'".((get_option('subscribe_reloaded_checked_by_default', 'no') == 'replies')?" selected='selected'":'').">".__('Replies to my comments','subscribe-reloaded')."</option>
                <!-- option value='digest'>".__('Daily digest','subscribe-reloaded')."</option -->
            </select>";
```

Comment: I am not familiar with this plugin, but the code looks like. +1

Comment: Neither am I, but I checked the docs: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option

Comment: All that and a posted answer in under 2 minutes? I wish I could +1 your answer again :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$checkbox_field = "<select name='subscribe-reloaded' id='subscribe-reloaded'> 
            <option value='none'>".__("Don't subscribe",'subscribe-reloaded')."</option> 
            <option value='yes'>".__('All','subscribe-reloaded')."</option> 
            <option value='replies'".((get_option('subscribe_reloaded_checked_by_default', 'no') == 'yes')?" selected='selected'":'').">".__('Replies to my comments','subscribe-reloaded')."</option> 
            <!-- option value='digest'>".__('Daily digest','subscribe-reloaded')."</option --> 
        </select>";
```

just moved the selected logic one step down, assuming everything else is correct and works as intended

Answer (score 0):

```
$checkbox_field = "<select name='subscribe-reloaded' id='subscribe-reloaded'>
            <option value='none'>".__("Don't subscribe",'subscribe-reloaded')."</option>
            <option value='yes'".((get_option('subscribe_reloaded_checked_by_default', 'no') == 'yes')?" selected='selected'":'').">".__('All','subscribe-reloaded')."</option>
            <option value='replies' selected>".__('Replies to my comments','subscribe-reloaded')."</option>
            <!-- option value='digest'>".__('Daily digest','subscribe-reloaded')."</option -->
        </select>";
```

Comment: This will result in two fields being marked as `selected`. You will need to take out the ternary or change the value it outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the code you have on the ALL line and put it on the other one instead...

```
$checkbox_field = "<select name='subscribe-reloaded' id='subscribe-reloaded'>
                <option value='none'>".__("Don't subscribe",'subscribe-reloaded')."</option>
                <option value='yes'>".__('All','subscribe-reloaded')."</option>
                <option value='replies'".((get_option('subscribe_reloaded_checked_by_default', 'no') == 'yes')?" selected='selected'":'').">".__('Replies to my comments','subscribe-reloaded')."</option>
                <!-- option value='digest'>".__('Daily digest','subscribe-reloaded')."</option -->
            </select>";
```